# Power App, Browse Screen, Is it possible to add additional field?

Tags: powerapp

It seems like I can only have 3 fields in my power app browse screen area. I've tried going to "edit fields" but I am not given the option to add additional fields.

[image]

Update:

Trying to add a 4th field, but 1) getting an error and 2) can this be repeated if i have multiple records in my browse screen?

update:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure you can. First of all you can add more fields from your data source if they are not already included. You do this by selecting the gallery (either on the canvas or from the left menu) and then clicking "Edit" - see below screen shot. From here you can add fields.

If you want to display these fields in your result/gallery you mark the first item in the gallery and click "Insert" on the top ribbon and select "Label". This label can then be set to show the fields from your data source with this formula in the Text property : ThisItem.. See screen shot below :)

Hope it helps :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I go to Edit Fields, I do not have the option to add an additional field.

Comment: Hmm, what menu do you see then? There should be a little "Add fields" button there. What is your data source, a SharePoint list?

Comment: ye sharepoint list - no add fields option! I can add fields in the other screens!

Comment: Ahh yes, got it. You need to mark the first element in your gallery (look at my second screen shot) and then click insert and the choose label. This label you can then bind to the extra column that you want to display by changing its Text property to something like ThisItem.<name of your SharePoint column>.

Comment: Cant get it to work - updated my question.

Comment: I think you are ALMOST there. So what you did by adding the label and giving the Text property is spot on. BUT.. you must add the label in the Gallery you have. So before you click insert label you MUST mark the first item in gallery just as in my screen shot 2 in my answer. Then the "ThisItem.Status" property will work. And yes, when you put a label in the first item in the gallery every item will get that label. The first item work as a template you can say. So mark the first item as in the photo above and add the label.

Comment: ok seems like i got it however getting an error still  sigh. updated question agian

Comment: I think we are getting even closer! It seems that your Status field is perhaps a managed metadata field or choice? Try to add a period and then type value (notice if the type ahead suggest something) so that the Text property looks like this:  ThisItem.Status.Value